# How to sort the file from lowest to highest including negative?

Tags: python, sorting

I wanted to sort these 2 files in ascending order including the negative values.

Value.txt =

```
-0.0059
0.0716
-0.0058
-0.0059
-0.1139
-0.1139
-0.0312
-0.0759
-0.0341
0.0047
-0.1813
-0.185
-0.06585
-0.023
-0.1438
0.05921
0.0854
-0.2039
-0.1813
0.05921
```

Character.txt =

```
man
king
new
one
text
gorilla
zilla
dulla
mella
killa
anw
testing
worry
no
time
test
kiss
queue
mouse
like
```

Expected output - This is the code I wish to receive

```
queue   -0.20399
testing -0.185
mouse   -0.181378
anw -0.1813
time    -0.1438
text    -0.1139
gorilla -0.1139
dulla   -0.0759
worry   -0.06585
mella   -0.0341
zilla   -0.0312
no  -0.023
man -0.0059
one -0.0059
new -0.0058
killa   0.0047
like    0.05921
test    0.0592104
king    0.0716
kiss    0.08544
```

My code: I tried to build this code but it wont work

```
with open("all.txt", "w+") as outfile:
        value= open("value.txt","r").read().splitlines()
        character= open("character.txt","r").readlines()
        a = sorted(list(zip(value,character)))
        for x in a:
            line = " ".join(str(uu) for uu in x)
            outfile.write("{}".format(line))
```

Somehow my output is wrong like this:

```
-0.0058 new
-0.0059 man
-0.0059 one
-0.023 no
-0.0312 zilla
-0.0341 mella
-0.06585 worry
-0.0759 dulla
-0.1139 gorilla
-0.1139 text
-0.1438 time
-0.1813 anw
-0.181378 mouse
-0.185 testing
-0.20399 queue
0.0047 killa
0.05921 like
0.0592104 test
0.0716 king
0.08544 kiss
```

I tried many other ways but still could not make it the expected output. Could anyone assist me please.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the type of data stored in `value`. Specifically, you may want to make sure that its elements are integers type and not strings.

Comment: I am sorry, it was stored in string. How can I convert it to integer instead?

Comment: Yeah, but what is the type of the individual elements of that list?

Comment: Sorry, it was in integer for the individual elements of that list.

Comment: Please double check your data type, i just ran your code (with your data in arrays) and it spit our what you want.

Comment: Yes but the order is incorrect for the negative part. I have already complete it and found the solution. thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the most efficient way. But if I should stay close to your code, I would add a few lines to convert items in `value`:

```
with open("all.txt", "w+") as outfile:
        value= open("value.txt","r").read().splitlines()
        # additional 2 lines:
        for i in range(len(value)):
            value[i] = float(value[i])
        character= open("character.txt","r").readlines()
        a = sorted(list(zip(value,character)))
        print(a)
        for x in a:
            line = " ".join(str(uu) for uu in x)
            outfile.write("{}".format(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(filename1) as infile_1:
    value =  [float(line.strip()) for line in infile.readlines()]
    character =  [line.strip() for line in infile_1.readlines()]

data = zip(value, character)
for i in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)[::-1]:
    print( "{1} = {0}".format(*i) )
```

**Output:**

```
queue = -0.2039
testing = -0.185
mouse = -0.1813
anw = -0.1813
time = -0.1438
gorilla = -0.1139
text = -0.1139
dulla = -0.0759
worry = -0.06585
mella = -0.0341
zilla = -0.0312
no = -0.023
one = -0.0059
man = -0.0059
new = -0.0058
killa = 0.0047
like = 0.05921
test = 0.05921
king = 0.0716
kiss = 0.0854
```

Comment: Sir, If allowed, could you tell me the difference between using {1}{0}.format(*i) and {}{}.format(i)... what is the "*" this for? Thank you

Comment: I am explicitly saying element 1 should be in front of element 0 in the result string. You can see the difference using `print( "{1} = {0}".format(*i) )
    print( "{} = {}".format(*i) )`

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I will try it.